# Replace text with an image in javascript

Tags: javascript, image, text, replace

I'm looking for a way to replace text with an image in javascript but I can not do it,

For example text:

```
<div><p class="YellowTxt">MyYellowTxt</p></div>
<div><p class="BlueTxt">MyBlueTxt</p></div>
<div><p class="GreenTxt">MyGreenTxt</p></div>
```

To have, a yellow, blue and green image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use innerHTML:

```js
function replace() {
  var el = document.getElementsByClassName('YellowTxt')[0]
  el.innerHTML = '<img src="" alt="image"/>'
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p class="YellowTxt">MyYellowTxt</p>
</div>
<div>
  <p class="BlueTxt">MyBlueTxt</p>
</div>
<div>
  <p class="GreenTxt">MyGreenTxt</p>
</div>

<hr />

<button onclick="replace()">Replace</button>
```